# Use combobox to filter records and populate a second combobox

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a little problem with passing the value of a combobox to a query which I would like to use to populate another combobox.

There is a large table containing the columns: AutoID, Projectname, Projecttype and some more which I want to filter for certain records.
The first combobox is populated by a different table containing: AutoID and Projecttype (I use this already to create the records in the previous table). This combobox is bound  to the first column (AutoID) but I display the second one. What I want
to do is to choose a "Projecttype" and populate the second combobox with all the corresponding records and display the "Projectname" for further processing.

I already read that it's not possible to use a combobox selection directly in a query and you have to go for a public function. I created this function (using the listindex to get the AutoID from the corresponding Projecttype) but can't pass it to the query (don't get any results although the value is correct!

Is there a "better" way to filter records (based on combobox selection) and populate a second combobox?

Thank you in advance!
Moritz

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `AutoID` and `Projecttype` in both tables? Looks like you could possibly do with some normalisation here.

To do what you want with the combo boxes, first of all define a global variable in the module where you've put your public function (I'll call it glngAutoID). The public function should just return the value of this variable, and then you can use this function in the query for the second combo box. In the AfterUpdate event of the first combo box put

```
glngAutoID = combo1
combo2.Requery
```

You shouldn't need to use the `ListIndex` property to get the AutoID because you've bound the combo box to the first column.